# ISO_C_BINDING: Impact on performance/optimization

Tags: c, optimization, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

In the context of MPI with derived data types, I've been told to be careful when using the `bind(C)` construct as it inhibits certain optimizations of the compiler. Consider this (rather unlikely example):

```
type, bind(C) :: myType
  integer(2) :: a
  complex    :: z
  integer(2) :: b
end type myType
```

Without the `bind(C)` statement the compiler would probably reorder the structure and group the two integers for better alignment. Especially for large structures and when trying to use auto-vectorization this will be beneficial.

With `bind(C)`, this regrouping is impossible (to stay compatible to `C`, where the compiler probably won't optimize that much). This would either lead to a large memory consumption (three words instead of two) if all elements are aligned to words, or to a loss of alignment. (At least, so I've been told. )

Until recently, I have never mixed C and Fortran, and I have never used derived types for MPI communications. In the near future, I'm going to look into mixed language programming, and these issues seem to be important.

So my question is two-fold:

- `bind(C)`: Does this misalignment play a role in "real-world" applications? Has anyone experienced performance/optimization issues here?
- `iso_c_binding`: Are there additional pitfalls when (additionally) using the module `iso_c_binding`? Which restrictions are imposed on the code and which optimizations are disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't worry that much. C compilers also do insert padding into structures, especially when the elements are not multiples of 4 bytes. Much worse would be `sequence`, but that is something different.

Try this equivalent of your derived type in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <complex.h>

typedef struct{
  int16_t  a;
  float complex b;
  int16_t c;
} t;

int main(){
 t o;
 printf("%x %x %x \n",&o.a,&o.b,&o.c);
 return 0;
}
```

My compiler (`gcc` on x86_64) alligns the components to addresses that are multiples of 4 bytes even without any optimizations. Even more, the allignment is exactly the same that `gfortran` chose with all optimizations enabled.

The same allignment is also used by `icc`, `ifort`, `suncc` and `sunf90`.

- The module `iso_c_binding` itself should have no impact on optimizations, bacuse it is only a collection of parameters, typedefs and procedures. It may force you to use more pointers than you would normally do though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So it seems the compiler does not optimize the order of the elements in the structure. I'm a little surprised since it seems to be quite simple to do so! I'll consult with the person that gave me the advice in the first place - maybe I got something wrong...

Comment: For maximum efficiency it is better to insert the padding. It occupies somewhat more space but acces to the components is faster and vectorization is easier.

Comment: I meant reordering of the elements... Like a,c,b instead of a,b,c. Then, the size of the structure is reduced to 12 instead of 16 bytes for both Fortran and C. There is still some padding to achieve alignment.

Comment: In C the compiler must not do that. In Fortran that would be possible, but not very beneficial for this case.

Comment: I don't quite understand - why would it not be beneficial? If I would (manually) reorder the structure, I would save some memory, and the individual components would still be aligned!

Comment: I think it is 4 + 8 + 4 in the original order and 4 + 4 + 8 reordered.

Comment: I see... When running your example in the original order I get the adresses `******f0 ******f4 ******fc`, as int16_t is two byte long I end up with 16 byte. The reordering leads to `******00 ******04 ******02`, so 12 byte in total (This is consistent to the `sizeof` I did in Fortran). So, in fact, the compiler is not aligning to multiples of 4 byte, but to 2? (I reduced the problem to 1byte integers and this did not change). Do I need an additional switch to enable aligning?

Comment: Ok, it did indeed use just 2 byte offset when reordered. It is implementation dependent. I do not see it an important thing and I never reorder my structures just to save two or four bytes per element. But we got quite far from the original topic. I do not see why should the Fortran compiler do this "optimization" automatically just to save a small amount of memory. Run-time performance is more important, at least for me.